# Mongoose: $sum in $project return only zero

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sum, lookup

I have a query using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) that "join" two models and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to select all fields that i need only, and in that [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) I need to [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) a value called `totalValue` but only return zero:

**My query**

```
User.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        storeKey: req.body.store,
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          cpf: "$cpf",      
          phone: "$phone",
          email: "$email",
          birthday: "$birthday",
          lastName: "$lastname"      
        },
        totalServices: {
          $sum: "$services"
        },    
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "schedules",
        "let": { "id": "$_id.phone" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$customer.phone", "$$id"] }}},
          { "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1 }}
        ],
        "as": "user_detail"
      }  
    },  
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        name: 1,
        cpf: 1,      
        phone: 1,
        email: 1,
        birthday: 1,
        totalServices: 1,
        totalValue: { $sum : "$user_detail.value" },   // here only return zero   
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        user_detail: 1
      }
    },
```

Comment: Because you didn't project the `value`. Specify it here `{ "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1, "value": 1 }}`

Comment: You didnt project/assign the .value

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your `value` field in the `user_details` projection to get it in the next aggregation stage

```
{ "$project": { "scheduleStart": 1, "scheduleEnd": 1, "value": 1 }}
```